# Regarding WPF, need advice on data sources and data binding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, data-binding

I am not new to WPF, but I am still a rookie. Let's say, I want to build an application which stores data about a person in an unique and separate file, and not in a database, sort of, like, Notepad. My application should do the following things.

1. It should be able to save a person's info in an unique file.
2. It should be able to open an user specified file and auto fill the properties/form.

How do I achieve this? Is the XML binding only way to achieve this, or is there an any other alternative? What I mean is, If I use XML binding I can write code which will enable the user to open and save different XML files, but I also read that binding to XML should be avoided from the architecture perspective. So, is there an alternative solution for my problem?

Comment: You can give a try for writing and retrieving things from/to a csv file . I think will be more appropriate  . If you don't prefer to use databases . Also having different files for each user is not at all a good idea

Comment: @csharpcorder First, thank you for the suggestion. I will try using csv files. Regarding different files for different users, you do maintain different word files for different articles you are writing, right? My application is more like Notepad and word. Actually, it's part of much bigger suite. Data base is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you try doing the stuff by using a Reading and writing the things to a CSV(Comma separated values) file(If not planning to implement databases) then you can achieve what you wanted.

Also if you are planning to have a separate file for each user its not at all a good idea.

Its not possible to explain everything thing here . So please have a look to link posted below , in which it has explained in detail how to achieve Reading and Writing to a csv file .

This example has been posted from here for getting full detail please look to following link [Reading and writing to a csv file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your requirement is to save person details into a unique file. If you really want to use that approach, one option is using XMLSerialization.

You can create your normal person object for data binding.

When you want to save data into the specific person's file you can serialize the object and save file with a proper name (person id or so)

When you want to get Person data back from the file, you can deserialize the it directly to a person object.

```
//  Serialize and write to file
Person person = myPerson;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(person.GetType());
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("person1.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, person);
}

//  Deserialize back to an instance
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("person1.xml"))
{
    var person= (Person)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For saving user data, such as sessions and settings. There are plenty of ways you can do this.

1. Saving to data to txt files. See [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)
2. Saving data to a database. See [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)
3. My personal favourite, saving to the `Settings` file. See [here.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/settings)

These are only *some* of the ways you can save data locally.

Note that I mentioned saving data to a database because it is something that you shouldn't completely knock, especially if you will be saving *lots* of data.

To answer your question more directly, I would suggest that you go with **option 3**. For relatively small sets of data, like user info and user settings, it would be your best bet to save them to the built in `Settings` file. It's dead easy.

Good luck!